# remove access rules ADT plugin Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, access-control

I want to remove the access rules in my android project.

Check [this](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-sdk/com/android/ide/eclipse/adt/internal/project/AndroidClasspathContainerInitializer.java.htm) link. This article tells you how to create access rules. But after creating an access rule, I want to modify or completely remove the access rule that I have in my project.